# css editor "Could not open the editor: Argument not valid"

Tags: android, css, eclipse

In an Android project, I'm trying to create a new css file in the assets folder (or edit an existing one) with Eclipse's built in CSS editor (the one with the 'S' inside the icon) in order to try and get some context sensitive help,as I'm fairly poor at CSS syntax.

Every time I attempt to open a .css file I get the error:

**Could not open the editor: Argument not valid**

The top of the details window shows

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4263)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4197)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4168)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.setStyleRanges(StyledText.java:9679)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.setStyleRanges(StyledText.java:9774)

Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong or missing?